# Setup file for win xp and win 7 from vb.net 2017

Tags: .net, vb.net

I’m new in vb.net. I have a solution in visual studio 2008 and want to continue with the project in any new version of visual studio eg. 2017. My question is how can I make setup file for windows xp/windows 7 in visual studio 2017 (I made setup for windows 10 and it’s ok)?

Comment: Windows XP has been end of life for several years now. It no longer gets any updates... not even critical security patches. It's irresponsible and dangerous to continue using it. Additionally, it no longer receives the new .Net releases, and hasn't since 4.0. So apps based off 4.5, like you would build with VS2017 by default, will not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run on Win XP and you've upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 you need to make sure the client PCs have the correct .Net version installed.

The .NET Framework 4 is supported on Windows XP, however, it will not run apps that require .NET Framework 4.5 or later versions.

Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp/